# secure connection to SQL from exe

Tags: sql-server, security, ssl, exe

i need a way to configer a working exe program to connect securly to SQL server

the program work with extrimly sensitive data and have to connet via a secure connection

Comment: By secure connection, do you mean over SSL? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Most modern drivers support TLS 1.2 to encrypt data in motion. What SQL Server API/driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to to this would be via domain trusts, if internally. If not, to properly follow a security pattern, you should have your application call an api endpoint using some form of authentication, e.g. oauth.

Once you have a connection between your application and the API, because the API is inside your firewall, you can then either use domain trust, or a username/password in the connection string.

If you are unfamiliar on how to write a connection string, there are plenty of examples on this site, or on connectionstrings.com.

thanks